# Proving that if $x>0$ then $\frac{x-(x^2+1)\arctan(x)}{x^2(x^2+1)}$ is less than $0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

How do I show that for $x>0$:
$$\frac{x-(x^2+1)\arctan(x)}{x^2(x^2+1)} < 0$$

I tried to do it somehow using the fact that $$\frac{\arctan(x)}{x} < 1$$ but still didn't figure it out...

Comment: why did you delete the last OP? I was giving you some other hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align}\frac{x-(x^2+1)\arctan x}{x^2(x^2+1)} < 0&\iff x<(x^2+1)\arctan x\\&\iff (1+x^2)\arctan x-x>0\end{align}$$ This is true iff $$\frac d{dx}\left[(1+x^2)\arctan x-x\right]=2x\arctan x+\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2}-1=2x\arctan x>0$$ which is true since both $x$ and $\arctan x$ are greater than $0$ when $x>0$. Hence result.

Comment: Sorry a lot I was wrong, try to fix!

Comment: Yes a stupid error but I can’t really see it! Sorry again for the misunderstanding and thanks a lot for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: definie $$f(x)=\arctan(x)-\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$ and Show that $$f'(x)=\frac{2 x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}>0$$ for $x>0$

Answer (score 1):

The question is equivalent to proving $\arctan(x)>\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ for any $x>0$, but this is trivial since
$$ \arctan(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2+1}> \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{x^2+1}=\frac{x}{x^2+1}.$$